# Using incorrect format specifier in printf()

Tags: c

I am trying to solve the next problem:

```
printf("%d", 1.0f); // Output is 0
```

So, I really do not know why it is so. The number 1.0 (32 bit in IEEE 754) has the next binary interpretation:

```
00111111 10000000 00000000 00000000
```

If convert this one to integer interpretation we get the next:

```
1 065 353 216
```

So, `sizeof(int) == sizeof(float) == 4 bytes`.

I know the float number in C will be converted into double by compiler, but I use `f` for float constant.
I tried different values and I counted the binary numbers, but I do not know. That is insanity.
I want to see the `1 065 353 216` in my console.

Comment: what `IDE` you use to compile it?

Comment: Visual Studio, but I also tried just compile using gcc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the incorrect format specifier to `printf`, you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), meaning you can't accurately predict what will happen.

That being said, floating point values are typically passed to functions via floating point registers, while integer values are typically passed on the stack.  So the value you're seeing is whatever happened to be sitting on the stack.

As an example, if I put that line by itself in a `main` function, it prints a different value every time I run it.

If you want to print the representation of a `float`, you can use a union:

```
union {
    float f;
    unsigned int i;
} u;
u.f = 1.0f;
printf("%d", u.i);
```

Comment: "While integer values are typically passed on the stack". In the standard x86-64 bit calling convention, the first 6 integer arguments are passed into registers rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, and r9.

Comment: In my way, behavior is defined, because I tried it using different compilers, but I got the same result.

Comment: @Danny Just because it happens to work for you in some situations doesn't mean it's defined.  The C standard has a very specific definition of Undefined Behavior and using the wrong format specifier is such an example.

Comment: @Danny "undefined behaviour" means "behaviour for which the C Standard imposes no requirements"

Comment: @Danny [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/questions/277486)